# Are there any alternatives to Dojo Toolkits grid?

Tags: dojo, grid

I think the [Dojo Toolkit's grid](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid) is kind of bad. Even the examples in their site ain't working. Are there any other alternatives? 
I'm thinking of using [Jquery's Ingrid](http://www.reconstrukt.com/ingrid/) instead, but would prefer to have all code in one javascript library.

Comment: Somebody screwed up and didn't copy a test data file on the community web site. Sorry about that. Usually when I want to see how to use stuff, and what is available I use the tests, which come with Dojo, e.g., this is one for the grid nightly deployed on the test VM: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/ It can be slow at times, so just deploy it locally and see for itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my former project we use [**jqGrid**](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and were pleased with it.

Grz, Kris.